# Why Does The Flex Compiler Get Confused If a Property Name Matches A Class Type?

Tags: actionscript-3, mxmlc

This is more of a rant than a question; but I am curious to know if anyone has some insight for me.  The application I am working on deals with a C# .NET backend; communication is achieved via a socket over which we push AMF objects.  The AMF object class definitions are generated by the server side team and I just have to use `registerClassAlias` on the flash side to link them up - pretty standard; the only difference being that as they come from a C# background they prefer to use UpperCammelCasing instead of lowerCamelCasing for property names.

Today I got a bunch of updated AMF objects which I dropped into the project; but I noticed that after updating my project would no longer compile - here are the class definitions in question:

*LeaderboardInfo.as Generated Class*

```
package com.generated {
    public class LeaderboardInfo {
        public var IsTied : Boolean;
    }
}
```

*GameResult.as Generated Class*

```
package com.generated {
    public class GameResult {
        public var LeaderboardInfo : LeaderboardInfo;
    }
}
```

*MXMLC error*

```
[mxmlc] .../GameResult.as(27): col: 32 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: LeaderboardInfo.
[mxmlc]         public var LeaderboardInfo : LeaderboardInfo;
[mxmlc]                                      ^
```

If I change the property name from `LeaderboardInfo` to `SomethingElse` then it compiles fine; my only guess would be that the Compiler can not distinguish between the property name and the type attribute, but is that really the case?!

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure it is. It also gets confused if your variable name is the same as your package name I think, as in public var generated:LeaderboardInfo, though I couldn't swear to it.

Comment: Could you not tinker with the .NET AMF serializer to make it serialize UpperCamelCase properties into lowerCamelCase ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you've just overwritten the "definition" of `LeaderboardInfo` to be a property and not a class, so when it's looking for the class, the property definition takes precedence, which breaks it.

I'd imagine you'd get the same result if you tried to do something like `public var return:int = 0;`